# Obtaining valid XP Professional licences?

Tags: windows-xp, active-directory, windows-sbs-2008, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

Hi Guys,

I realise I'm probably on a fools errand, but I gotta ask: is there *any* way to obtain valid, legitimate XP Pro licences?

I've recently purchased a new SBS2008 server. My 3 XP-Pro machines will connect to the domain without problems... unfortunately, I've also got two laptops both running home editions of windows (1 XP, 1 Vista) to contend with.

Windows 7 is out of the question, given the age of the machines. Running them off the domain is also out of the question.

If anyone has any ideas, I'd be highly appreciative.

Cheers.

Comment: your best best is to contact a Microsoft reseller, they will know the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buy Windows 7 Pro licenses. They come with downgrade rights to XP Pro. If you purchase them through Volume Licensing, you get XP Pro download and keys.

Comment: I'm assuming this is valid world-wide? (I'm in Australia)

Comment: It is. Mostly because there still is a LOT of stupid software in the enterprise marketplace that was not upgarded by developers to actually run under XP.